# Magento 2 - Create a theme - display products issue

Tags: themes, magento2

After installing Magento 2 with composer and importing sample data, I would like to create a new theme. I'm following the [frontend developer guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) but when I apply my new theme, I can't see any of my products in categories. The left menu with filters is still here but no products are displayed.

Any solution for me please ?

PS: Sorry for my english...:)

Comment: Could you please share some code of your own theme? We can't know what's going wrong otherwise. Also, a screenshot would be helpful to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are my files**

[image]

registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/OORun/running',
    __DIR__
);
```

theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>Running</title>
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> 
     <media>
         <preview_image></preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>
```

**no products**

[image]

Edit : 
I found that the problem is related to /etc/view.xml

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
        <width>150</width>
        <height>150</height>
    </image>
</images>
```

When I delete this file, all products are displayed correctly.
I have just copied the documentation example, I don't understand what I did wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The luma theme is built with 'cms' features. They are defined in the backend in

***Content -> Widgets***

For example the widget "Home Page". To use the same "Home Page" widget with your custom theme you have to add a new one with the same parameter from the luma "Home Page" widget except the **"Design Package/Theme"** parameter, which is now your custom theme.

In general the widgets are linked to a theme name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the issue was the /etc/view.xml file on my custom theme. 
I deleted the file and worked fine.